# LPCSTR and wchar_t issue. Linker error because of parameter mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I a porting a large amount of code from Visual Studio to mingw unicode enabled project and I ran into this issue.It seems that the parameters I am passing from the derived class to the base class do not match. Atleast thats my assumption. I am suspecting that the issue is with the type `LPCSTR`  Looking into this type in mingw I get the follwoing typedef

```
  typedef CONST CHAR *LPCSTR,*PCSTR;
```

Now this is the base class

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    CBasePin(
        __in_opt LPCSTR pObjectName,        
        __in CBaseFilter *pFilter,     
        __in CCritSec *pLock,           
        __inout HRESULT *phr,              
        __in_opt LPCWSTR pName,        
        PIN_DIRECTION dir);         
#endif
```

This is the class that inherits from the base class and passes the parameters to the base class.

```
CAsyncOutputPin::CAsyncOutputPin(
    HRESULT * phr,
    CAsyncReader *pReader,
    CAsyncIo *pIo,
    CCritSec * pLock)
  : CBasePin(
                TEXT("Text Pin"), 
                pReader,
                pLock,
                phr,
                TEXT("Output"), 
                PINDIR_OUTPUT
            ),

    m_pReader(pReader),
    m_pIo(pIo)
  ,m_bQueriedForAsyncReader(false)  ////
{
}
```

This is the linker error I am getting at the constructor initialization list

```
undefined reference to `CBasePin::CBasePin(wchar_t const*, CBaseFilter*, CCritSec*, long*, wchar_t const*, _PinDirection)'|
```

any suggestions on why I am getting this linker error. I am a bit puzzled as to why this is a linker error. I was guessing if it was a type mismatch or something it would show up as a compiler error. Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue for Mingw 64bit gcc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your CBasePin has a parameter `LPCSTR pObjectName` (which is of type  `const char*`) and a parameter `LPCWSTR pName` (whichis of type `const wchar_t*`) and in your call to it you're using `TEXT`-macro on a char-literal ,so both those literals getting the L-prefix making them `const wchar_t*` when **UNICODE** is defined ,so there is a type mismatch on the pObjectName.
If UNICODE is not defined then you would get the same error but on pName.

Remove the first TEXT and it should be Ok (for UNICODE that is).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the TEXT macro? You have one char * parameter and one wchar_t * parameter, and it can't do the right thing for both.

Just write what you mean. Something like

```
"Text Pin", ..., L"Output", ...
```